# upgrade macOS to Sonoma 14.0 crashes MySql WorkBench

Tags: macos, mysql-workbench

after upgrading my MacBook to macOS Sonoma 14.0 I'm unable to work consecutively on MySql WorkBench. it keeps crashing after the second or third execution of a query or stored procedure.

has anyone encountered this specific problem & managed to solve it with re-installing?

I have run an ordinary upgrade of the macOS and used to apps stopping to work, but this time it does not recover

here is the bug report:

Comment: Feel free to put a bug report on MySQL's issue tracker

Comment: Ya could be a bug, I wonder if you try to boot into a pc environment with Parallel or Bootcamp if it still has the same problem?  Could help them pinpoint the issue if you make a report.

Comment: the bug report is very long, highlights: {"app_name":"MySQLWorkbench","timestamp":"2023-09-28 17:29:22.00 +0300","app_version":"8.0.12.CE","slice_uuid":"8e974f6b-9dcf-309d-9356-2abd72b7a2b3","build_version":"1","platform":1,"bundleID":"com.oracle.workbench.MySQLWorkbench","share_with_app_devs":1,"is_first_party":0,"bug_type":"309","os_version":"macOS 14.0 (23A344)","roots_installed":0,"name":"MySQLWorkbench","incident_id":"3CB92A24-3551-44DF-A218-AB4F7F141E67"}

Comment: another thing from the error report:
Thread 0 Crashed::  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libcairo.2.dylib                      0x10559ca3f DataProviderReleaseCallback + 15

Comment: Please post the bug report **on their issue tracker**, not on StackOverflow

Comment: reported the bug

Comment: Upgrading to MySQL Workbench 8.0.34 solved this for me. (I had 8.0.31 before). (Apple Silicon MacBook)

Comment: This has been reported to the their bug tracker multiple times already, and the standard MySQL response is that MacOS Sonoma is not supported by Mysql. https://www.mysql.com/support/supportedplatforms/workbench.html Go figure.....

Comment: I'm using version 8.0.34 (ARM) and when I try to open a model the program closes by itself.